# python opencv version mismatch

Tags: python, linux, opencv, pip, sudo

I have a conflict between which version of opencv is installed vs which is used.

I installed opencv using apt-get and then used pip to upgrade to latest version.

```
$ sudo pip3 freeze | grep opencv
opencv-python==4.6.0.66

$ sudo python3 -c 'import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)'
4.5.5

$ sudo python3 -c 'import cv2; print(cv2.__file__)'
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py
```

As you can see, pip sees `opencv 4.5.5` but python3 sees `opencv 4.6`

I am using raspbian:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

How do I get python3 to see the correct version of opencv? (4.6)

Comment: that's because you use `sudo`... either that or you have multiple pythons, or multiple packages of OpenCV, or who knows what else. just start from scratch. there isn't any information in this question that would make it answerable.

Comment: I used sudo with pip as well as with python, shouldn't they be the same? What other info can I provide?

Comment: opencv-python is the python interface to the opencv library. It is not opencv.

Comment: @stark that's splitting hairs and irrelevant to the situation. anyone installing `opencv-python` is getting OpenCV, just accessible through Python and not C++.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz OP is printing the version of opencv-python which is unrelated to the version of opencv installed on the system.

Comment: @stark As mentioned - I did not install opencv in any other way other than installing pyhton-opencv, so I can't see how that's relevant. upgrading python-opencv is supposed to upgrade opencv as well

Comment: opencv is a submodule of opencv-python. See https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/.  You can build opencv-python with any version of opencv and call it any version that you want.  Why should the two different things have the same version?

Comment: look, you don't know OpenCV. OpenCV's source itself contains the code for python bindings, and none of that requires the `opencv-python` repo and its build scripts. there can never be a version "mismatch" because there simply aren't different things, they're one and the same. the `opencv-python` repo merely contains build scripts to make a wheel, nothing more. don't imagine problems where there can't be any. and don't try to be right by going "but it's _possible_ to break this in such a way". that'd be derailing.